# Deep copy of a derived python object

Tags: python, object, pyqt, derived-class, deep-copy

I have an object in python that is derived from `QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem` with a few basic attributes and methods. After calling `deepcopy` on a reference to this object, I get an error saying that `underlying C/C++ object has been deleted` when I try to use the copy. I had received this error before, and it occured when I didn't call the base class' constructor in `__init__` so I assume this error is because the `QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem` is not being copied.

How do I go about specifying this? All I know is that there is a `__deepcopy__` method for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

`QGraphicsPixmapItem` is not copyable. It inherits `QGraphicsItem` which is declared using the `Q_DISABLE_COPY` macro which is the same mechanism used for `QObjects` to disable copying. [The documentation explains it a bit better](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qobject.html#Q_DISABLE_COPY).